# WSO2 Analytics: No StreamDefinition for streamId loganalyzer:1.0.0 present in cache

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-das

I am using WSO2 APIM 2.5.0 and Analytics 2.1.1.SNAPSHOT along with it. Everything was working fine as I have been using it for some days now.

Suddenly, I have started getting error as below:

```
  Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.exception.EventConversionException: No StreamDefinition for streamId loganalyzer:1.0.0 present in cache
at 

 org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.thrift.converter.
ThriftEventConverter.createEventList(ThriftEventConverter.java:166)
```

Then, to analyse it, I restarted the Analytics application and then I found this in the startup

```
INFO {org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.internal.ApplicationManager} -  
Deploying Carbon Application : org_wso2_carbon_analytics_apim-
1.0.0.car...
WARN {org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.internal.ApplicationManager} -  
No artifacts found to be deployed in this server. Ignoring Carbon 
Application : org_wso2_carbon_analytics_apim-1.0.0.car
```

There were no changes in the carbon apps from both the applications (apim and analytics)

Can some one please let me know why this error started coming and how to resolve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to the server roles of analytics serve not matching with the server roles defined in artifact.xml file for each stream. If the roles "DataAnalyticsServer" and "ComplexEventProcessor" doesn't exist as server roles, the analytics artifacts won't be deployed.

To check whether the server roles are there;

1. Login to the APIM analytics server Management Console.
2. Please add the below 2 server roles from *Configure > Server Roles > Add New
   Server Role* (if it's not already there).

   ```
   DataAnalyticsServer 
   ComplexEventProcessor
   ```
3. Remove the current *ANALYTICS_HOME/tmp* folder in the analytics servers. Redeploy the capp

Also check whether the ServerRoles property in *ANALYTICS_HOME/repository/conf/carbon.xml* contains an entry as shown below. For capps deployment, it identifies the roles that can be acted by the current server.

```
   <ServerRoles>
        <Role>DataAnalyticsServer</Role>
        <Role>ComplexEventProcessor</Role>
    </ServerRoles>
```

Is there any reason as to why you are using Analytics 2.1.1 with WSO2 APIM 2.5.0? The recommended approach is to to use Analytics 2.5 with APIM 2.5.0.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I have already did these changes:
1) Checked the roles mentioned in the artifacts files.xml and it referred to DataAnalyticsServer and
2) Cleared the tmp folder as well.
Even after making these changes, it didnot work. So, I reinstalled the application with older databases, which made it worked. However, this I could not understand yet why this happened. I was using the same application from few months now and didnot get any issues. I will keep a check and update here if I find any cause of such behavior.

Comment: is there any link where I can update APIM Analytics 2.1.1 to 2.5.0